# Copying views in xtensor

Tags: c++, numpy, xtensor

Is there a function similar to numpy copy for copying views? If not, what is the simplest way to deep copy complex views? The copy constructor still points to the same internal values, which is fine most of the times, but there are times when a deep copy is needed.

Comment: What do you mean with complex views? A view of a view? Shouldn't a copy of a view always be the same, not depending on if it is a copy of the first or the tenth view, since it is creating a new object anyways? If I am wrong, I am thankful for an explanation.

Comment: More like a view of a view of a strided view of a view. And the problem is that all of those, and any of their assignment ponts to the same underlying elements. So if i need to modify all beforehand will change. Which would be fine if the xtensor had a copy function like  numpy, but i have not found it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply assign the view to an xarray or an xtensor object if you know its number of dimensions:

```
xt::xarray<double> cmy_copy(view);
```